# String cannot be converted to nvarchar - but everything is already cast to DT_WSTR

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which has been working for years, and all of a sudden it has stopped working, with the error:

An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

All of my strings are already converted to DT_WSTR in derived columns. Something must have changed in my input flat file format, because it still works on files produced a week ago. I've analysed the difference between the working version and the new failed version in beyond compare, and there are no differences in format or encoding. It has 100+ columns, and with no indication of which column is causing the problem, it is very hard to diagnose.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haha, actually, not all the columns were being case to DT_WSTR. Once I made sure every single field was being cast to DT_WSTR of the appropriate length, the import succeeded.